# Using a macro for the coordinate in \coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

It seems that the two lines in the following code are not equivalent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\coord{(0,0)}
\begin{document}
%  \tikz \coordinate at \coord;
 \tikz \node[coordinate] at \coord {};
\end{document}
```

Namely, the first (commented) line gives an error when used in place of the second.  My understanding of the `\coordinate` command is that it is equivalent to `\node[coordinate] {}`, so am I missing something or is this a bug?

This question seems to have a similar flavor as [Use macro as coordinate in pgfplots plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15846/use-macro-as-coordinate-in-pgfplots-plot) (among others) but this is not an issue of expandability: `\coord` is obviously fully expandable and indeed, works in what appears to be the same context in a nearly identical command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a normal picture `\node` is equivalent to `\path node` and `\coordinate` is equivalent to `\path coordinate`:

```
\node:
macro:->\tikz@path@overlay {node}

\coordinate:
macro:->\tikz@path@overlay {coordinate}

\tikz@path@overlay:
macro:#1->\let \tikz@signal@path =\tikz@signal@path \pgfutil@ifnextchar <{\tikz@path@overlayed {#1}}{\path #1}
```

(It is a little different for overlays, e.g. use in `beamer`)

The difference between both is that `\node` is more flexible in the syntax i.e. can have different things follow. It can have a name or not, for example and the order is not fixed. Because of this the following material is always expanded before it is parsed. This takes care of the `\coord` macro. However, `\coordinate` has quite a fixed syntax of `\coordinate[<options>] (<name>) at (<position>);`, and therefore are parsed differently.

Your example code doesn't have the `(<name>)` part which causes the first error. An unnamed coordinate doesn't make sense. However, even with the name it still generates an error. The following parsing macro is used which requires a `(` somewhere after the `at`. The `[ ]` part is added using the default value beforehand if it isn't present.

```
\tikz@@coordinate@@at:
macro:[#1](#2)at#3(->\def \tikz@coordinate@caller {\tikz@fig ode[shape=coordinate,#1](#2)at}\tikz@scan@one@point \tikz@@coordinate@at@math (
```

So one way to solve this would be to move the `( )` to the outside of the `\coord` macro. This seems to work, at least in your MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\coord{0,0}
\begin{document}
 \tikz \coordinate (name) at (\coord);
 \tikz \node[coordinate] at (\coord) {};
\end{document}
```

Comment: My little question is unworthy of this answer!  So should I take away from this that it is *accidental* that `\node` allows macros to expand into its input syntax, or that it is *unintentional* that `\coordinate` is more rigid than it?  Depending on the answer to that, what *is* the right way of using a presupplied `at` coordinate in a `coordinate`?

Comment: @Ryan: The expanding while processing `\node path` is intentionally. The non-expansion of `\node coordinate` is also intensionally, most likely for efficiency. More macros would be needed otherwise. Besides using `coordinate (name) at (\coord);` as shown above you could use `\edef` to expand the command beforehand: `\edef\mycommand{\noexpand\coordinate (name) at \coord;}\mycommand`.

Comment: I think I'll go with using `\node[coordinate]`, then, since in fact I don't want to arrange things so that the parentheses are not in `\coord`.  Thanks!