# How to pass a \def coordinate to macros

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, errors, expansion, coordinates

I am trying to pass a \def coordinate to a [macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/draw-arc-in-tikz-when-center-of-circle-is-specified) and got an error. Below is the code. The macro with direct passing works, but the two commented out lines don't.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   % required for \centerarc
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5){ \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
        \def \cpt {(1,2)};
        \draw (0,0) node [right] {cpt position coordinate = \cpt } ;
        \centerarc[ultra thick, cyan](1,2)(-30:30:2);       
        %\centerarc[ultra thick, purple] \cpt (-30:30:1);
        \def \cpt2 {(0,3)++(180-30:3)};
        %\centerarc[ultra thick, purple] \cpt2 (-30:30:3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that in the pgfmanual, 2.15 Specifying Coordinates, it used \def this way:

```
   \def\rectanglepath{-- ++(1cm,0cm) -- ++(0cm,1cm) -- ++(-1cm,0cm) -- cycle}
    \draw (0,0) \rectanglepath;
```

Don't know why mine doesn't work?

Comment: Never say "I got an error". *Which* error? `\def \cpt2 <other stuff>`. Defines `\cpt` so it expands to `2` and leaves `<other stuff>` in the input stream. You can't use numbers in macro names. (At least, you can if you really need to, but not like this.)

Comment: Similar question: [tikz pgf - Using a macro for the coordinate in \coordinate - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/using-a-macro-for-the-coordinate-in-coordinate), [using macros in tikz/pgf - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63685/using-macros-in-tikz-pgf)

Comment: There's no problem with the first one where you just expand the macro inside a node. You have spurious `;` everywhere, which causes warnings but no error. The others run into expansion issues. If you tell us why you want to do this, we may be able to be more helpful. Not that you can't make this work, but it will probably be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues here. The most complex involve expansion, as indicated in the comments. Let's start with the simplest.

First, you have a sprinkling of excess semicolons. These don't cause errors, but you do get warnings about the character not existing in `null font`. This is pgf/Ti*k*Z's way of pointing out you have garbage stuff which you might have thought was real content.

- `\def<spec>{<definition>}` does not need to be followed by a semicolon.
- If you define a semicolon into a macro, you need to take this into account when using it. So either delete the final semicolon from the definition of `\centerarc` or don't follow it by a semicolon when you use it.

For example,

```
  \def \cpt{(1,2)}
  \draw (0,0) node [right] {cpt position coordinate = \cpt } ;
  \centerarc[ultra thick, cyan](1,2)(-30:30:2)
```

will avoid the warnings.

Second, `((0,3)++(180-30:3))` is not a valid coordinate. This will give an error regardless of whether `\def` is involved. I'm not certain what you meant here, but I'm guessing `($(0,3)+(180-30:3)$)` and have amended the definition on that basis.

Third, you can't use a numeral in a macro name. Only letters are allowed.

```
      \def \cpt2 {($(0,3)+(180-30:3)$)}
```

[Thanks to [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701586/how-to-pass-a-def-coordinate-to-macros#comment1744676_701593) for correcting me here.]
This redefines the macro `\cpt` so it expects to be followed by `2`  and then expands to `{($(0,3)+(180-30:3)$)}`. So trying to use `\cpt2` without a following space will cause an error.

There are special ways around this restriction, but there's no need of them here. We can just use a different name. For example,

```
      \def \cpttwo {($(0,3)+(180-30:3)$)}
```

Fourth, you have serious expansion issues here. When you put `\cpt` into a node, all is well. When you try to substitute it for a literal coordinate, things go haywire.

```
\centerarc[ultra thick, purple]\cpt(-30:30:1)
```

TeX reads tokens one-by-one from a stream, which is like a long line of tokens. `\centerarc` is the first token here. That's a macro, so TeX looks up its definition and finds that it absorbs `[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)` so it reads on to scoop up `#1`, `#2`, `#3`, `#4` and `#5` in order to slot them into the appropriate places in the definition. That means TeX expects to see a `[` first. No problem there. It knows `#1` is everything until the next `]`. So `#1` is `ultra thick, purple` and that can be slotted into `\centerarc`'s definition. Next it expects `(` but instead it finds `\cpt` which doesn't match the template it has for `\centerarc`. So you get an error. To correct this, you need `\cpt` to be expanded before `[ultra thick, purple]`. You could do that with a whole bunch of `\expand after`s, but you'd need to jump every token separately i.e. the `[`, the `u`, the `l` and so on. That's a lot of typing and a recipe for inscrutable code.

```
  \def\myopts{[ultra thick, purple]}
```

This turns that group of tokens into a single token `\myopts`, making it easier to skip. So, we want

```
  \expandafter\myopts\cpt
```

But if we just do that, it still won't work because `\centerarc` will now see `\expandafter` rather than `[` as the first token. So we need to expand `\centerarc` after expanding `\expandafter`.

```
\expandafter\centerarc\expandafter\myopts\cpt(-30:30:1)
```

This gets `\cpt` to expand first, so TeX will see

```
\centerarc\myopts(1,2){-30:30:1}
```

Now the problem is `\centerarc` expects `[` to begin with and not `\myopts`. So we need another `\expandafter`.

```
\expandafter\expandafter\centerarc\expandafter\myopts\cpt(-30:30:1)
```

But that's not quite good enough, because `\expandafter\expandafter\centerarc` expands `\centerarc` first, which was where all the problems started. Hence, we need a third `\expandafter` at the beginning for a total of five.

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\centerarc\expandafter\myopts\cpt(-30:30:1)
```

Similarly, for the case with `\cpttwo`,

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\centerarc\expandafter\myopts\cpttwo(-30:30:3)
```

I've referenced an answer below which explains the same idea in a simpler case, so you might want to read that if the multiplicative effects of `\expandafter` above seem unduly alarming. (I did try doing it token-by-token to show what `\myopts` avoids, but I got entangled and gave up.)

### Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   % required for \centerarc
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5){\draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
  \def \cpt{(1,2)}
  \draw (0,0) node [right] {cpt position coordinate = \cpt } ;
  \centerarc[ultra thick, cyan](1,2)(-30:30:2)   
  % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701593/   
  % i gwestiwn Leon Chang: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/701586/
  % refs: Caramdir https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18316/
  \def\myopts{[ultra thick, purple]}
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\centerarc\expandafter\myopts\cpt(-30:30:1)
  \def \cpttwo {($(0,3)+(180-30:3)$)}
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\centerarc\expandafter\myopts\cpttwo(-30:30:3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: three arcs and a node]

Needless to say, I don't recommend *implementing* this!

Comment: `\def \cpt2 {($(0,3)+(180-30:3)$)}` defines macro `\cp` with `2␣` (digit 2, followed by space) as parameter text. Then, TeX requires that the parameter text follows `\cp` and `\cp` expands to the definition text `($(0,3)+(180-30:3)$)`. If the parameter text is not given, TeX complains with an error message.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I knew I shouldn't answer this.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the insights. To a user, macros are more restrictive and error-prone than functions.

Comment: @LeonChan Are you talking about `expl3`?

Comment: @cfr Any document on expl3 or \expandafter is appreciated. I couldn't even find doc. on macros \def<spec>{<definition>}.

Comment: @LeonChang So what did you mean by 'function'? I would not necessarily tangle with `expl3` at this point, but `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3` are probably the key references (but not really aimed at beginners). Overleaf has some quite good stuff on TeX's handling of tokens and such.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It does not define macro `\cp`. It defines macro `\cpt`. ;-)

Comment: @cfr By function, I mean a C or Python function. But looks like I can only find [tikzmath function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702130/how-to-pass-coordinate-parameters-to-a-function/705155#705155) which can only take numbers. So I would say macro is better than a function in this respect.

Comment: @LeonChang `expl3` functions can absorb arguments of all sorts. In `expl3` functions are syntactically distinguished from variables, whereas at the TeX level, both would be macros. This has nothing to do with Ti*k*Z. `expl3` is now part of core LaTeX. So that's why I asked if you meant `expl3` when you mentioned functions.

Answer (score 2):

With a command `\path #2 coordinate (ZZ);` We could do better with the ZZ point name to make sure it is not used elsewhere in your code.

EDIT: I forgot to change `ctp2` to `cpttwo`, (the cfr's answer) and the `++`

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   % required for \centerarc

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycenterarc}{O{ultra thick, purple} m m m m}
    {
        \path #2 coordinate (ZZ);
        \draw[#1] ($(ZZ)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def \cpt {(1,2)}
        \draw (0,0) node [right] {cpt position coordinate = \cpt } ;
        \mycenterarc[ultra thick, cyan]{\cpt}{-30}{30}{2}
        \mycenterarc{\cpt}{-30}{30}{1}
        \def \cpttwo {(0,3)+(180-30:3)}
        \mycenterarc{\cpttwo}{-30}{30}{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the code `\NewDocumentCommand{\mycenterarc}{O{ultra thick, purple} m m m m}`? Is there a manual for \NewDocumentCommand?

Comment: You can read https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2021-JAW-TUB-tb130wright-newdoccmd.pdf 
A tutorial `expl3` https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/
A documention 'interface3`

Comment: and `xparse` documentation

Comment: `xparse` is deprecated. These commands are now documented in the core LaTeX docs and `interface3` isn't helpful for `\NewDocumentCommand`. @LeonChang is probably looking for `usrguide.pdf` and, possibly, `clsguide.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

Within tikzpicture-environments, too, spaces and ends of lines of .tex-input usually get tokenized as space tokens when TeX's reading apparatus is in state M. This may affect macro-argument-grabbing with macros like `\centerarc` that process delimited macro arguments.
Within tikzpicture-environments stuff not yielding visible output is due to some null-font being in effect and due to other adjustments not related to tokenization and not related to macro-argument-grabbing during the stage of expansion but related to typesetting.

Expansion is suppressed when TeX is gathering tokens for macro arguments and hereby probably is scanning for argument delimiters.
E.g., if you define
`\def\foo#1/Delimiter{Argument: #1}` and
`\def\bar{Tokens/Delimiter}`, then
`\foo\bar` won't work out as in the course of gathering the tokens belonging to `\foo`'s delimited macro argument #1, `\bar` won't get expanded.
But `\foo Tokens/Delimiter` does work out.
`\expanded{\unexpanded{\foo}\bar}` also works out as the `\expanded`-expression yields
`\foo Tokens/Delimiter`.

Thus you can do with some expansion trickery.

You need to define `\cpt2` to deliver replacement text with curly braces `{...}` surrounding the inner of the `(...)`-expression so that delimiter-matching of `\centerarc` will grab the correct set of tokens as its delimited macro argument `#2`.

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\@stopromannumeral{\chardef\@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   % required for \centerarc
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5){\draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);}
        \def\cpt{(1,2)}
        \draw (0,0) node [right] {cpt position coordinate = \cpt};
        \centerarc[ultra thick, cyan](1,2)(-30:30:2)
        \expanded{\unexpanded{\centerarc}[ultra thick, purple]\cpt(-30:30:1)}
        % ++ doesn't work - I don't know if just +  is the right thing,
        % but with the expression (0,3)+(180-30:3) the stuff between 
        % the outermost parentheses ( and ) needs to be wrapped in 
        % curly braces to ensure it all is grabbed as \centerarc's
        % delimited argument #2 and not just (0,3) is grabbed as
        % \centerarc's delimited argument #2: ({0,3)+(180-30:3}) .
        % Curly braces surrounding an entire delimited argument are
        % stripped off when in the replacement text #2 gets replaced
        % by the argument gathered from the token stream:
        \CsNameToCsToken\def{cpt2}{({0,3)+(180-30:3})}
        %%%%
        \expanded{\unexpanded{\centerarc}[ultra thick, purple]\CsNameToCsToken{cpt2}(-30:30:3)}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having learnt from psascal974's answer, I was able to use \newcommand to implement it which circumvents using the \def\centerarc macro.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   % required for \centerarc
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw[loosely dashed] (0,0) grid [step=2] (5,5)
        %Below either one is working; 
        \newcommand{\centerarc}[5]{\path #2 coordinate (xy); \draw[#1] ($(xy)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5) }
        %\newcommand{\centerarc}[5]{\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (yz) at #2; \draw[#1] ($(yz)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5) }        
        \def \cpt {(1,2)}
        \draw (0.3,0.5) node [right] {cpt position coordinate = \cpt } ;
        \centerarc{ultra thick, orange} {\cpt} {-30}{30}{1};
        \def \cptTwo {(4,2)+(180-30:3)}
        \centerarc{ultra thick, purple} {\cptTwo} {-30}{30}{3};
        \def\rectanglepath{-- ++(1cm,0cm) -- ++(0cm,1cm) -- ++(-1cm,0cm) -- cycle}
    \draw (0,0) \rectanglepath; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assumed you wanted the original syntax ;). You could use `\NewDocumentCommand` here, perhaps.