# Using Macro Defined Lists in TikZ/PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots

I want to be able to use a macro to specify a list (it is a constant list, i.e. will not change throughout the document) and use this macro rather than hard code the list contents in the TikZ/PGFplots for readability. This problem was mentioned in [this earlier question about `foreach` loops](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-slas), but was not the main thrust of that question.

Here is a related question on [how to maintain consistency with TikZ and pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/how-to-maintain-consistency-with-tikz-and-pgfplots), and its continuation on the [use of a macro as coordinate in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15846/use-macro-as-coordinate-in-pgfplots-plot/16072), but these related to specifying coordinates, and not lists.

In the MWE below, Example 1's solution is based on [this question on using a macro defined list in a foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list) which suggested to not enclose the macro defined list in a curly brace. This works fine for TikZ, so no problem yet.

However, in PGFplots things are different. The solution in Example 2 to using a `foreach` is from [the above referenced question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-slas), and works great as long as I do **not** use a macro for the list, but I would prefer to use a macro here.

In Example 3, I can easily use a macro defined list for the `xtick`, but am **not** able use it for `xticklabels`.

So, is there a consistent way that I can always define a macro for a list and then use it without having to worry about the context of its use? If not, is there a way to change the definition of the list and/or its use for Examples 2 and 3 that work in those situations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*{\XTickLocationList}{-2, -1, 1, 2}
\newcommand*{\XTickLabelsList}{a, b, c, d}
\newcommand*{\XTickLocationsAndLabels}{-2/a, -1/b, 1/c, 2/d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   % Example 1
\draw [->][gray, thin](-3,0) -- (3,0) node[blue, right] {$x$}; 
\draw [->][gray, thin](0,-3) -- (0,3) node[blue, above] {$y$};

%\foreach \x/\l in {-2/a, -1/b, 1/c, 2/d} { % Works
%\foreach \x/\l in {\XTickLocationsAndLabels} {  % Does not compile
\foreach \x/\l in \XTickLocationsAndLabels {  % Works
    \draw [thick, red]
        (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt)
        node [red, above] {\l};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}   % Example 2
\begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=0, 
    axis y line=center, 
    axis x line=middle, 
    xmin=-3, xmax=3, 
    ymin=-3, ymax=3,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xtick={0},  xticklabels={}
    ]

\foreach \x/\l in {-2/a, -1/b, 1/c, 2/d}{ % Works
%\foreach \x/\l {\XTickLocationsAndLabels}  % Does not compile
%\foreach \x/\l \XTickLocationsAndLabels  % Does not compile
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot
        [mark=none,color=red, thin, samples=2]%
        coordinates{ (\x,-0.05) (\x,0.05) }
            node [red, below] {\l};
    }
    \temp
} 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}    % Example 3
\begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=0, 
    axis y line=center, 
    axis x line=middle, 
    xmin=-3, xmax=3, 
    ymin=-3, ymax=3,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    %xtick={-2, -1, 1, 2}, % Works
    %xtick=\XTickLocationList, % Works
    xtick={\XTickLocationList}, % Works
    xticklabels={a, b, c, d}  % Works
    %xticklabels={\XTickLabelsList}  % Compiles, but wrong results
    %xticklabels=\XTickLabelsList  % Compiles, but wrong results
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Knowing that this comment is *not* really what you asked for, I still want to mention one possible approach: did you consider using a style instead of `\XTickLabelsList`? For example `\pgfplotsset{x tick labels list/.style={xticklabels={a,b,c,d}}` will allow you to write `x tick labels list` whenever you want that macro. Concerning the original question: I can investigate why the list is expanded for xtick but not for xticklabels. Perhaps this should be unified.

Comment: @Christian: Small typo in your solution: Need three `}` at end. With that fix, this would be fine if I could say `\pgfplotsset{x tick labels list/.style={xticklabels={\XTickLabelsList}}}`. So, that the list is only defined once and can be accessed in the `\begin{axis}` environment as `x tick labels list` and as `\XTickLabelsList` within a `foreach`.

Comment: I see. I fear you stumbled over an issue in pgfplots which causes the construction xticklabels={\macro} to be treated in a different way than in \foreach. I'll take a note in the pgfplots todo list. But that means you may want to use a different solution until a solution has been found and released.

Comment: I also provided an alternative answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15684/how-to-maintain-consistency-with-tikz-and-pgfplots

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given the restrictions discussed in my comments above, I suggest using a more technical approach - which is absolutely reliably and fully portable (but less commonly known in LaTeX).

I mean, the problem is that pgfplots does not understand `xticklabels={\XTickLabelsList}`. More precisely: it takes the argument as (single) list entry rather than expanding it. To be honest, I am not even sure if someone might *want* to use such a feature (a one-element-list witch a macro as content).

So, what we need is to provide the *content* of `\XtickLabelsList` programmatically.

Well, here is the promised solution:

```
\edef\temp{%
  \noexpand\pgfplotsset{%
      x tick labels list/.style={xticklabels={\XTickLabelsList}}
  }%
}
\temp
```

It defines `\temp` to contain the "fully expanded" content of the argument in braces ("e"xpanded "def"inition). If a `\noexpand` occurs in the argument of `\edef`, the "fully expanded" content of the item following `\noexpand` is the item itsself, i.e. `\noexpand\pgfplotsset` stays `\pgfplotsset`. But `\XTickLabelsList` will be replaced by its content. Note that any macro which might occur in `\XTicjLabelsList` might also be expanded (there are other techniques to avoid that. In case you need them, pose the question again or research in my TeX-programming-notes.pdf which should be shipped with pgfplots).

Anyway, the `\temp` macro will finally contain `\pgfplotsset{.....{a,b,c,d}}}` (type `\show\temp` to verify it). Executing `\temp` will activate the changes and you can readily use the style afterwards with `x tick labels list`.

Comment: This new suggestion does not quite work for me. If I use the above `\edef`, **and** have `xticklabels={\XTickLabelsList}` in the `\begin{axis}` I get one label `a,b,c,d` as I was without the `\edef`. If I remove the statement form the `\begin{axis}`, the points get labelled with their numerical values, not the alpha list that I specified.  Perhaps I am not using it properly.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I fear one point got lost on my lengthy explanation: the solution above does only work if you provide the `\edef` in your preamble and use `x tick labels list` instead of `xticklabels={\XTickLabelsList}` in your axes.

Comment: At least 10 people *would like* such a feature.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @ Frank! In the meantime, a related feature has been added to `pgfkeys` in general: one can write `xticklabels/.expand once={\XTickLabelsList}` with the desired effect and without the technical overhead in my example. Would that address the use-case?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: The `.expand once` seems to work well for me. Much cleaner than the above `\edef` solution.