# Macro to access a specific member of a list

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to be able to have a macro access a specific element of a list. The following code works, however requires me to have two separate macros: one that accepts a list, and the other that accepts the name of a macro that contains the list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\GetListMemberA}[2]{%
    \foreach \a [count=\i] in {#1} {%
        \IfEq{\i}{#2}{\a\breakforeach}{}%
    }%
    \par%
}%

% This is same as above except does not have {} around #1
\newcommand*{\GetListMemberB}[2]{%
    \foreach \a [count=\i] in #1 {%
        \IfEq{\i}{#2}{\a\breakforeach}{}%
    }%
    \par%
}%


\newcommand*{\MyList}{a1,b2,c3,d4,e5}%

% These work if the foreach uses {#1} (ie, with the curly braces)
This should print "b": \GetListMemberA{a,b,c,d,e}{2}%
This should be blank: \GetListMemberA{a,b,c,d,e}{6}%

% These work if the foreach uses #1 (ie, without the curly braces}
This should be "a1": \GetListMemberB{\MyList}{1}%
This should be "c3": \GetListMemberB{\MyList}{3}%
This should be blank: \GetListMemberB{\MyList}{6}%

\end{document}
```

This question on [TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list) suggest to remove the braces around the macro when using a foreach, and that is how I was able to come up with this solution.

So, how can I change this so I don't have to have two macros?

I don't think this issue is related to [Using Macro Defined Lists in TikZ/PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17833/using-macro-defined-lists-in-tikz-pgfplots) as that was specific to lists used to label tick marks on axis.

Comment: Related Question: [Get n-th element of a list (with etoolbox, or not)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80154/get-n-th-element-of-a-list-with-etoolbox-or-not).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make the macro work both with inline lists and with lists in macros, you can use `\edef` to assemble the loop command, with `\noexpand` before every macro except for the arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

% This works both with inline lists and with macros containing lists
\newcommand*{\GetListMember}[2]{%
    \edef\dotheloop{%
    \noexpand\foreach \noexpand\a [count=\noexpand\i] in {#1} {%
        \noexpand\IfEq{\noexpand\i}{#2}{\noexpand\a\noexpand\breakforeach}{}%
    }}%
    \dotheloop
    \par%
}%


\newcommand*{\MyList}{a1,b2,c3,d4,e5}%

This should print "b": \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{2}%
This should be blank: \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{6}%

This should be "a1": \GetListMember{\MyList}{1}%
This should be "c3": \GetListMember{\MyList}{3}%
This should be blank: \GetListMember{\MyList}{6}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works. One minor change: Need to add a `%1 after the the `}}`. Otherwise end up with extra spaces.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\StrBetween` and your code does not require calc or pgf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}

% This works both with inline lists and with macros containing lists
\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1]{,#1,},,\par}%

\newcommand*\MyList{a1,b2,c3,d4,e5}

This should print "b": \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{2}
This should be blank: \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{6}

This should be "a1": \GetListMember{\MyList}{1}
This should be "c3": \GetListMember{\MyList}{3}
This should be blank: \GetListMember{\MyList}{6}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The macro `\mypkg_expand:Nw` expands or not the argument of a function depending on whether it is unbraced, or braced. The `\GetListMember` is just defined through that macro, and `\GetListMember_aux:nn` recieves the list (expanded once) as a first argument and the index as a second. Now `\clist_item:nn` starts counting at 1. Negative arguments start from the right, but require a recent version of the `expl3` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \mypkg_expand:Nw #1
  {
    \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NTF \c_group_begin_token
      { #1 } { \exp_args:NV #1 }
  }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \GetListMember
  { \mypkg_expand:Nw \GetListMember_aux:nn }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \GetListMember_aux:nn #1 #2
  {
    \clist_item:nn {#1} {#2}
    \par
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\MyList}{a1,b2,c3,d4,e5}

This should print ``b'': \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{2}%
This should be blank:  \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{6}%
This should be ``a1'':   \GetListMember\MyList{1}%
This should be ``c3'':   \GetListMember\MyList{3}%
This should be blank:  \GetListMember\MyList{6}%

\smallskip

This should print ``b'': \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{-4}%
This should be blank:  \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{-6}%
This should be ``a1'':   \GetListMember\MyList{-5}%
This should be ``c3'':   \GetListMember\MyList{-3}%
This should be blank:  \GetListMember\MyList{-6}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't cope with the case when you try it with one element list that happens to be a control sequence. It would be possible to make the difference according to whether a brace follows or not, but I don't find this very robust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetListMember}{mm}
 {
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n { #1 } } { \token_if_cs_p:N #1 }
   {% it's a control sequence
    \clist_item:Nn #1 { #2 }
   }
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\MyList}{a1,b2,c3,d4,e5}%

This should print ``b'': \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{2}

This should be blank: \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{6}

This should be ``a1'': \GetListMember{\MyList}{1}

This should be ``c3'': \GetListMember{\MyList}{3}

This should be blank: \GetListMember{\MyList}{6}

This should be ``a1'': \GetListMember\MyList{1}

This should be ``c3'': \GetListMember\MyList{3}

This should be blank: \GetListMember\MyList{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, I'd prefer using `*` in the case we want a control sequence (or conversely, according to your preferences).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GetListMember}{smm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% * means control sequence
    \clist_item:Nn #2 { #3 }
   }
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\MyList}{a1,b2,c3,d4,e5}%

This should print ``b'': \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{2}

This should be blank: \GetListMember{a,b,c,d,e}{6}

This should be ``a1'': \GetListMember*{\MyList}{1}

This should be ``c3'': \GetListMember*{\MyList}{3}

This should be blank: \GetListMember*{\MyList}{6}

\end{document}
```

[image]