# How to define a command to feed the contents of a list into an \ifcase construct?

Tags: macros, conditionals, comma-separated-list

It's common to use an `\ifcase` construct to redefine a command depending on the value of a counter. The following example illustrates this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\sectioncolor{}

\renewcommand\sectioncolor{%
  \ifcase\value{section} brown\or red\or blue\else olive\fi}
\pretocmd{\section}{\color{\sectioncolor}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}

\end{document}
```

The above redefinition of `\sectioncolor` using `\ifcase` implies manually feeding the colors in the `\ifcase` construct. What I would like to achieve is to have a command, say `\ColorList`, having as argument a comma separated list of variable length containing the colors to be used, and then redefine `\sectioncolor` to use the colors of the list depending on the section counter. So for example, referring to my sample code, using

```
\ColorList{brown,red,blue,olive}
```

would be equivalent to

```
\renewcommand\sectioncolor{%
  \ifcase\value{section} brown\or red\or blue\else olive\fi}
```

and

```
\ColorList{yellow,magenta,cyan,orange,blue}
```

would be equivalent to

```
\renewcommand\sectioncolor{%
  \ifcase\value{section} yellow\or magenta\or cyan\or orange \else blue\fi}
```

but. of course, without having to manually feed the colors into the `\ifcase`. How can this be done?

Comment: I was hopeful that [Macro to access a specific member of a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21559/macro-to-access-a-specific-member-of-a-list) would have solved this, but I am not able to adapt those solutions to work in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is similar to @egreg's solution and avoids `\ifcase` in favour of just cycling the list, but the coding is probably a bit simpler (unless you'be already loaded expl3 for other reasons)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\ColorList#1{\def\xcolorlist{#1}}
\let\xsection\section
\def\section{\expandafter\xxcycle\xcolorlist,\xcolorlist\xsection}
\def\xxcycle#1,#2{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
   \color{#1}%
   \ifx\xcolorlist#2\else
    \xcycle#1,#2%
   \fi
  \fi}


\def\xcycle#1,#2\fi\fi#3\xcolorlist{\fi\fi\ColorList{#2#3#1}}



\ColorList{yellow,magenta,cyan,orange,blue,green!30,red!50!black}
%\ColorList{yellow}
%\ColorList{}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I find that \ColorList{yellow} (ie, with only one member) fails. I don't know how important this is. Anyway, I have eked out a patch but I don't feel qualified to edit your answer.

Comment: @AhmedMusa  thanks I fixed it (I hope) for `{yellow}` and `{}` edge cases.

Answer (score 14):

Since you are using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) already, you can use `\docsvlist` and redefine `\do` appropriately.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\newcounter{listitem}
\newcommand\sectioncolor{%
  \setcounter{listitem}{-1}% At this point, section counter has not been incremented
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{listitem}% Increment list counter
    \ifnum\value{listitem}=\value{section}\color{##1}\fi% Match list counter with section counter
  }
  \docsvlist{yellow,magenta,cyan,orange,blue,green!30,red!50!black}%
}
\pretocmd{\section}{\sectioncolor}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\section{Section Two}
\section{Section Three}
\section{Section Four}
\section{Section Five}
\section{Section Six}
\section{Section Seven}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and clean, I was looking forward to this one while reading the other answers.

Answer (score 14):

This will cycle over the listed colors:

```
\documentclass[convert,border=2,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor,xpatch,xparse}
\xpretocmd{\section}{\sectioncolor}{}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ColorList}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_gonzalo_colors_seq { , } { #1 }
 }
\seq_new:N \g_gonzalo_colors_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\sectioncolor}{ }
 {
  \seq_gpop_left:NN \g_gonzalo_colors_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_gput_right:NV \g_gonzalo_colors_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \color { \l_tmpa_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ColorList{yellow,magenta,cyan,orange,blue,green!30,red!50!black}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}

\end{document}
```

At every call of `\sectioncolor` the color to use is popped from the top of the sequence and put back at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I know this is an old answer but this is what I found ;). Could you explain why you'd use a sequence here rather than a comma list? I was trying to do something similar with `clist`s and I realised that I wasn't sure whether I should be using those or sequences. Is there somewhere this is explained? (I understand that a sequence could use something other than a comma, but for a case like this where it is a comma anyway, I'm not very clear.)

Comment: @cfr `clist`s are more for “user interface”; sequences are more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess there is no reason I can't carry on with them, now I've started. (Given the general inefficiency of my code, I don't think I will notice any loss ;).)

Answer (score 10):

There are probably a dozen standard methods for parsing comma-separated lists, but I don't know any of them, so here's my ad hoc solution (with a grain of salt :)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@else@ifc{\noexpand\else}
\newcommand\@or@ifc{\noexpand\or}

\def\commalisttoifcase#1,%
{%
  #1\@commalisttoifcase
}

\def\@commalisttoifcase#1,#2,%
{%
  \ifx\empty#2\empty
    \@else@ifc\unexpanded{#1}%
    \expandafter\@gobble
   \else
    \@or@ifc\unexpanded{#1}%
    \expandafter\@commalisttoifcase
  \fi
  #2,%
}
\newcommand\ColorList[1]
{%
  \edef\next
  {%
    \noexpand\renewcommand\noexpand\sectioncolor{%
      \noexpand\ifcase\noexpand\value{section} 
      \commalisttoifcase#1,,\noexpand\fi
    }%
  }
  \next
}

\makeatother
```

Then

```
\ColorList{yellow,magenta,cyan,orange,blue}
\show\sectioncolor
```

gives

```
> \sectioncolor=\long macro:
->\ifcase \value {section} yellow\or magenta\or cyan\or orange\else blue\fi .
```

Comment: The LaTeX kernel uses `@for`, `@for\next:=\alist\do{...}`...

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I know that much, but I'd have to look in the code to find out whether it's expandable :-)

Answer (score 7):

ConTeXt provides `\defineconversion` and `\convertnumber` commands which cycle through the list of elements (or applies a macro to the number). This is useful for things like footnote markers (`\dagger`, `\star`, etc.), but can be easily overloaded for other tasks as well.

```
\defineconversion
  [colors]
  [red,blue,green]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [color={\convertnumber{colors}{\currentsectioncountervalue}}]

\starttext
\dorecurse{10}
  {\section{Section \recurselevel}}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple solution using `xstring`.  It does not do the proper error control (what happens if there are more sections than colors), but correctly processes the first and the last section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\def\ColorList#1{\gdef\@ColorList{#1}}
\def\sectioncolor{%
  \StrCount{\@ColorList}{,}[\@tempa]% The length of the
  \@tempcnta\@tempa\relax%                list
  \advance\@tempcnta by 1\relax
  \ifnum\the\c@section<2\relax\StrBefore{\@ColorList}{,}% The
                            % special case of first section 
  \else\ifnum\c@section=\the\@tempcnta\relax % The special case of
                            % last section 
    \advance\@tempcnta by -1\relax
    \StrBehind[\the\@tempcnta]{\@ColorList}{,}%
  \else  % The general case
    \@tempcntb=\the\c@section\relax
    \advance\@tempcntb by -1\relax
    \StrBetween[\the\@tempcntb,\the\c@section]{\@ColorList}{,}{,}%
  \fi\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ColorList{brown,red,blue,olive}

\noindent\sectioncolor{}

\section{AAAA}

\sectioncolor{}

\section{BBBB}

\sectioncolor{}

\section{CCCC}

\sectioncolor{}

\section{DDDD}

\sectioncolor{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In case you need more control, here is another solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltxkeys}
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
% Keys:
\ltxkeys@declarekeys[GM]{bodystyle}[bdsty@]{%
  cmd/body name/section/
    \edef\bdsty@bodyname{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \ifltxkeys@dec\else
      \ifblankTF{#1}{%
        \@latexerr{Section body name can't be empty}\@ehd
      }{%
        \ifinsetTF{,#1,}{,chapter,section,subsection,paragraph,}{}{%
          \@latexerr{Section body name not recognized}\@ehd
        }%
      }
    \fi;
  cmd/style list command//
    \edef\bdsty@stylelistcommand{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \ifltxkeys@dec\else
      \ifsingletokenFT{#1}{%
        \@latexerr{Style command \detokenize{#1} isn't a single token}\@ehd
      }{%
        \ifescapedTF{#1}{%
          \ifx#1\@undefined
            \@latexerr{Style command \detokenize{#1} is undefined}\@ehd
          \else
            \ifx#1\@empty
              \@latexerr{Style command \detokenize{#1} is empty}\@ehd
            \fi
          \fi
        }{%
          \@latexerr{Style command \detokenize{#1} isn't escaped}\@ehd
        }%
      }%
    \fi;
  cmd/repeated code//
    \edef\bdsty@repeatedcode{\unexpanded{#1}};
  cmd/exit code//
    \csn@edef{bdsty@\bdsty@bodyname @exitcode}{\unexpanded{#1}};
}

% User commands:
% \newbodystyle[<keyval>]
\newcommand\newbodystyle[1][]{%
  \ltxkeys@setkeys[GM]{bodystyle}{#1}%
  \cptexpanded{%
    \letcsntocsn{bodystyle@\bdsty@bodyname}{\bdsty@bodyname}%
    \csn@def{\bdsty@bodyname}{%
      \def\noexpand\n@wstylelist########1,########2\noexpand\newbodystyle{%
        \expandcsonce\bdsty@repeatedcode{########1}%
        \xdef\expandcsonce\bdsty@stylelistcommand{%
          \unexpanded{\ifblankTF{####2}{}{\unexpanded{####2},}%
          \unexpanded{####1}}%
        }%
      }%
      \noexpand\xifinsetTF{,}{\noexpand\expandcsonce
      \expandcsonce\bdsty@stylelistcommand}{%
        \unexpanded{\expandafter\n@wstylelist}\expandcsonce
          \bdsty@stylelistcommand\noexpand\newbodystyle
      }{%
        \unexpanded{\expandafter\n@wstylelist}\expandcsonce
          \bdsty@stylelistcommand,\noexpand\newbodystyle
      }%
      \noexpand\usename{bodystyle@\bdsty@bodyname}%
    }%
  }%
}
% \restorebodystyle{<body name list>}
\newcommand*\restorebodystyle[1]{%
  \cptdocommalist{#1}{%
    \ifcsndefTF{bodystyle@##1}{%
      \letcsntocsn{##1}{bodystyle@##1}%
      \csname bdsty@##1@exitcode\endcsname
    }{%
      \@latexerr{Heading name '\detokenize{##1}' wasn't saved}\@ehd
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Example document:
\begin{document}
% Fonts:
\def\usefontpallete{%
  \def\say{Current style: {\tt\detokenize\expandafter{\currstyle}}\par}%
  \def\sayb{\def\currstyle{normal font}\normalfont}%
  \def\style{\def\temp####1{\def\currstyle{####1}####1}\temp}%
  \def\sectionstylelist{\tt,\sf,\bf,\rm,\it,\mdseries}%
  \def\subsectionstylelist{\sl,\sc,\upshape}%
}
% Colors:
\def\usecolorpallete{%
  \def\say{Current color: {\tt\detokenize\expandafter{\currstyle}}\par}%
  \def\sayb{\def\currstyle{normal color}\normalcolor}%
  \def\style{\def\temp####1{\def\currstyle{####1}\color{####1}}\temp}%
  \def\sectionstylelist{orange,blue,red,red!50!black,ForestGreen}%
  \def\subsectionstylelist{olive,magenta,cyan}%
}
\parindent0pt
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Title}
Normal style, default style.

\usecolorpallete
% Let's ignore font pallete in the current run:
%\usefontpallete

\newbodystyle[
  body name          = section,
  style list command = \sectionstylelist,
  repeated code      = \style,
  % Code to execute when \restorebodystyle is called:
  exit code          = \sayb
]
\newbodystyle[
  body name          = subsection,
  style list command = \subsectionstylelist,
  repeated code      = \style,
  exit code          = \sayb
]
% A style may also be defined for 'paragraph'.

\section{Title}
\say aaa
\section{Title}
\say bbb
  % Higher order cycles (eg, subsection) are independent of lower order 
  % cycles (eg, section):
  \subsection{Subtitle}
  \say ccc
  \subsection{Subtitle}
  \say ddd
  \subsection{Subtitle}
  \say eee
  \subsection{Subtitle}
  \say fff
  \subsection{Subtitle}
  \say ggg
  % Restore subsection to default style:
  \restorebodystyle{subsection}
  \subsection{Subtitle}
  \say hhh
\section{Title}
\say iii
\section{Title}
\say jjj
\section{Title}
\say kkk
\restorebodystyle{section}
\section{Title}
\say lll
\section{Title}
\say mmm
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun, here is a cyclic loop that won't bomb out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifcyclicstop
% \cyclicdo[<max loop run>]<callback><listcmd>
\robust@def*\cyclicdo{\cpt@testopt\@cyclicdo{10000}}
\robust@def\@cyclicdo[#1]#2#3{%
  \cyclicstopfalse
  \def\cyclicnr{0}%
  \def\@cyclica##1,##2{%
    \edef\cyclicnr{\the\numexpr\cyclicnr+1}%
    \ifnumcmpTF\cyclicnr>#1{%
      \@latexerr{Max loop number #1 exceeded by \string\cyclicdo}\@ehd
    }{%
      #2{##1}%
      \ifboolTF{cyclicstop}{%
        \begingroup
        \def\@cyclica####1\cyclicdo{\endgroup}%
        \let\@cyclicb\@cyclica
      }{}%
      \expandafter\ifcseqTF\cpt@car##2x\car@nil\cyclicdo{%
        \@cyclica##1,\cyclicdo
      }{%
        \@cyclicb##1,##2\@cyclicb
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \def\@cyclicb##1,##2\@cyclicb##3\cyclicdo{\@cyclica##2##3##1,\cyclicdo}%
  \ifcsemptyTF{#3}{}{\expandafter\@cyclica#3,\cyclicdo}%
}
\makeatother

% Example document:
\begin{document}
\def\colorlist{yellow,magenta,cyan,orange,blue,green!30,red!50!black}
%\def\colorlist{yellow}
%\def\colorlist{}
\def\do#1{%
  % Do only 10 cycles:
  \ifnum\cyclicnr>10\relax\cyclicstoptrue\fi
  {\color{#1}Current: \tt\detokenize{#1}}\endgraf
}
\cyclicdo\do\colorlist
\end{document}
```

[image]