# Make enumerate numbering different colours

Tags: color, enumerate

Is there a way to make the different numbers within the enumerate environment different colors.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\end{enumerate}
```

I wish to make the 1. green, the 2. orange and the 3. red

i.e Not the text that follows but the preceding number a particular colour

Thanks

Comment: Congratulations to you question. I guess there is no other question on the whole stackexchange which was answered by only four (!) people (as of Jan. 26, 2013: Heiko, Gonzalo, Werner, egreg), having a weight of 650.000 reputation points! If points were gravity, your thread would instantly turn into a black hole. And something else is symptomatic: no solution uses Lua.

Answer (score 10):

The following example defines colors `enum1`, `enum2`, ... using `\colorlet` of package `xcolor`. Then it hooks into `\labelenumi` to add the color command with the color that consists of the value of counter `enumi`. For deeper nesting levels of the `enumerate` environment, `\labelenumii` upto `\labelenumiv` can also be changed accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{enum1}{green}
\colorlet{enum2}{orange}
\colorlet{enum3}{red}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfColorUndefined}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar=`\\ %
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\string\color @#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\labelenumi{%
  \IfColorUndefined{enum\the\value{enumi}}{}{%
    \color{enum\the\value{enumi}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Extension for nested lists:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{enum1}{green}
\colorlet{enum2}{orange}
\colorlet{enum3}{red}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfColorUndefined}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar=`\\ %
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname\string\color @#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\DefColorListLabel}[1]{%
  \expandafter\preto\csname label#1\endcsname{%
    \IfColorUndefined{enum\the\value{#1}}{}{%
      \color{enum\the\value{#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\DefColorListLabel{enumi}
\DefColorListLabel{enumii}
\DefColorListLabel{enumiii}
\DefColorListLabel{enumiv}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third\label{third}
    \item Fourth
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Nested first
      \item Nested second
      \item Nested third\label{nestedthird}
      \item Nested fourth
    \end{enumerate}  
  \end{enumerate}
  References: \ref{third} and \ref{nestedthird}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result nested]

Comment: Dear Heiko, when I begun reading the code, I thought »Heiko has written that!«. Scrolling down, it was true and it seems I recognise your style of coding sometimes.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach. Using `\ColorList`, you define a comma separated list of colors to be applied to the labels; the colors will cycle if required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\ColorList#1{\def\xcolorlist{#1}}
\let\@xitem\@item
\def\xitem{%
\@inmatherr\item
\@ifnextchar [\@xitem{\@noitemargtrue \@xitem[\@itemlabel]}}
\def\item{\expandafter\xxcycle\xcolorlist,\xcolorlist\xitem}
\def\xxcycle#1,#2{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
   \color{#1}%
   \ifx\xcolorlist#2\else
    \xcycle#1,#2%
   \fi
  \fi}
\def\xcycle#1,#2\fi\fi#3\xcolorlist{\fi\fi\ColorList{#2#3#1}}
\xpatchcmd{\@xitem}{\hskip \labelsep}{\hskip \labelsep\normalcolor}{}{}
\makeatother

\ColorList{green,orange,red,magenta}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
  {\ColorList{cyan,gray,olive}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item[($\ast$)] Fourth
  \item Fifth
  \item Sixth
  \end{enumerate}}
\item Fourth
\item Fifth
\item Sixth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used a variation of [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53642/3954) to [How to define a command to feed the contents of a list into an \ifcase construct?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53617/3954).

Answer (score 6):

The following just updates `\labelenumi` - the macro responsible for printing the label:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\renewcommand\labelenumi{%
  {\ifcase\value{enumi}% 0
  \or\color{green}% 1
  \or\color{orange}% 2
  \or\color{red}% 3
  \else\fi%
  \arabic{enumi}.}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \item Third
  \item Last
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will cycle through colors defined for each level. A new `\listcolors` command will redefine the colors from that point on.

With this implementation, color cycling will restart from where it ended; it's possible to modify the setup in various ways, for instance making any level one `colorenumerate` start again from red.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listcolors}{ m m }
 {
  \listcolor_set:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{colorenumerate}{ O{} }
  {\enumerate[format=\listcolor_format:,#1]}
  {\endenumerate}

\tl_new:N \l_listcolor_currentcolor_tl

% syntactic sugar
\cs_new:Npn \listcolor_makename:n #1
 {
  g_listcol_level_ \int_to_roman:n { #1 } _seq
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \listcolor_set:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_gclear_new:c { \listcolor_makename:n { #1 } }
  \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { \listcolor_makename:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \listcolor_format:
 {
  \seq_if_empty:cF { \listcolor_makename:n { \int_use:c { enit@depth } } }
   {
    % Fetch the color name from the start of the sequence
    \seq_gpop_left:cN  { \listcolor_makename:n { \int_use:c { enit@depth } } }
                       \l_listcolor_currentcolor_tl
    % Put it back at the end of the sequence
    \seq_gput_right:cV { \listcolor_makename:n { \int_use:c { enit@depth } } }
                       \l_listcolor_currentcolor_tl
    % Use the current color
    \color{ \l_listcolor_currentcolor_tl }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\listcolors{1}{red,green,blue}
\listcolors{2}{cyan,magenta,yellow}

\begin{document}
\begin{colorenumerate}
\item Abc
\item Def
  \begin{colorenumerate}
  \item Inner
  \item Again
  \item[??] Well
  \end{colorenumerate}
\item Ghi
\item Jkl
\end{colorenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]