# colorize label of specific enumerate item

Tags: color, lists, enumitem

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item[red] 2
\end{enumerate}
```

For itemize I could use `\item[\textcolor{red}{--}]` or something, but for enumerate that does not really work.

I already tried
`[\textcolor{red}{\arabic{enumi}}]` - which oddly started with 1 again
`[\textcolor{red}{\value{enumi}}]` - which resulted in a pdflatex error
`[\textcolor{red}{\theenumi}]` - which printed the (custom) `ref=` for that entry - and also counted from 1 on

Comment: You can adapt the answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167454/231952. For example, in the first answer by @egreg, replace the first `*` with `\color{red}` (and adjust the open paren)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following method works with or without the `enumitem` package being loaded, and it works for both `enumerate` and `itemize` environments.

Observe that the macro `\myitem` is set up to take one optional argument, and that the default value of the optional argument is `red`. Thus, `\myitem` will create an item number that's red, while `\myitem[blue]` will create an item number that's -- you guessed right -- blue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\myitem[1][red]{\color{#1}\item\color{black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   A
\myitem B
\myitem[blue] C
\item   D
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I also came up that idea. Is there a latexway to define a makro or so? like "\reditem" "\blueitem" or even better: \myitem[red]

Comment: @weltio - I'll edit my answer to show how to set up a macro called `\myitem` that takes an optional argument, with the default value of the optional argument being `red`.

Comment: @Mico Do you think that this question is it a duplicate of this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155968/make-enumerate-numbering-different-colours

Comment: @Sebastiano - I don't think so. The earlier question required an automatic cycling thru a list of colors; this one does not.

Comment: @Mico Surely is my low level for English language. Very often I find that I don't understand what the user is asking for.