# How can I break a macro / how to realize a switch or array-structure

Tags: macros

I'm looking for a way to realize a macro with a `switch/case` control structure (or an `array` solution), as it exists in every programming language.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{givemea}{box}{}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{drawmea}{circle}{}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{applesidontlikeare}{green}{}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{life}{is full of surprises}{}%
}
\begin{document}
\foo{life}
\end{document}
```

As you can think of, if I have let's say 500 entries the process will slow down very much, as it compares to *every single value* in the macro. A `\break` or `\return` command would be very useful, so the macro aborts if the value is found.
Addition: My strings also will contain numbers (at every position).

Or are there any packages I can use for the job?

(Since there will be a lot of entries, I consider to split up the one macro into many: `\fooa`, `\foob`, ... So, if I invoke `\foo{life}` it checks the first letter `l`, and then invokes `\fool{life}`. That also will speed up the process.)

Comment: Comparing every item is going to be slow: a split if possible is useful, even if it's only say halving the total length.

Comment: Another alternative is an "associative jump array" using `\csname foo@branch@#1\endcsname` where the command `\foo@branch@gievemea` contains the code for this value. This will use the internal hash which is really efficient. You can guard this with `\ifcsname` and make it more robust with `\detokenize`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I agree, but my strings will also have numbers, see my comment to David Carlisles answer

Comment: @musicman No problem, just define the commands with `\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo@branch@abc123(bar);baz\endcsname{expansion text}`

Comment: As for splitting up, using the internal hash will be efficient for millions of entries; see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/how-to-implement-low-level-arrays-in-tex).

Comment: Using the `\@namedef` trick is certainly the way to go here but depending on the application you have in mind you might also find the package `pgfkeys` useful. Adopting a key-val interface could make your code very readable and flexible, while avoiding reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't want a linear series of string equality tests you want a hash lookup:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\newcommand*\foo[1]{\csname FOO-#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\setfoo[1]{\expandafter\def\csname FOO-#1\endcsname}

\setfoo{give1mea}{box}
\setfoo{draw2mea}{circle}
\setfoo{applesidontlikeare!!}{green}
\setfoo{life}{is full of surprises}
\setfoo{apple4dinner}{see?}


\begin{document}
\foo{life} \foo{apple4dinner}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't use that, because I also will have number in the arguments: `apple4dinner`, `4bears`, `goodn8`

Comment: @musicman That isn't a problem just use `\@namedef{apple4dinner}{this}` (somewhere were `@` is a letter eg after `\makeatletter` or in a package

Comment: @musicman updated answer to demonstrate digits and ! in mames

Comment: If `\foo` is not `\long`, shouldn't `\setfoo` also not be `\long`?

Comment: @AndrewStacey not really one is saying whether you want to allow `\par` in the _name_ the other whether you want to allow `\par` in the value. You may as well make `\foo` not long as `\par` would generate an error in csname anyway, but you may want `\par` in the value

Comment: @AndrewStacey A `\par` in the argument to `\setfoo` would give an error anyway (`Missing \endcsname`).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You misunderstand where I want to put the `\long`.  _Since_ you define `\foo` using `\newcommand*` then I think you should also define `\setfoo` using `\newcommand*` as the arguments are used in the same way.  Whether or not you want to allow `\foo` and `\setfoo` to eat a `\par` is, as both you and egreg point out, simply a matter of choosing your error message.  But whatever you choose, you should be _consistent_ about your choice.

Comment: @AndrewStacey oh I was thinking I'd defined `\setfoo` to have two arguments (in which case my comment above would be true) but I see I took a shortcut and only defined it with 1. Now I have a moral dilemma  of whether to comment that you were correct or amend the answer so my comment is correct

Comment: @AndrewStacey I added a `*` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I applaud your sense of morality.

Comment: I've decided to accept your answer, because it's the most 'basic', it doesn't need any package etc. - thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 10):

The `expl3` programming layer for LaTeX3 provides `\str_case:nnF` and related functions: these only compare 'as far as required':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \strcases \str_case:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \strcases{#1}%
    {%
      {givemea}           {box}
      {drawmea}           {circle}
      {applesidontlikeare}{green}
      {life}              {is full of surprises}
    }%
    {No match found!}%
}
\begin{document}
\foo{life}
\end{document}
```

Note that for very long lists the comparison still has to be made for each item until a hit is found, which will get slower for very long lists when the item is near the end.

An alternative approach, similar to [David's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180798) in the sense it uses a lookup table, is to use a `prop`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_my_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {givemea}           {box}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {drawmea}           {circle}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {applesidontlikeare}{green}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_my_prop {life}              {is~full~of~surprises}
\newcommand* \foo [1]
  {
    \prop_get:NnNTF \l_my_prop {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
      { No~match~found! }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\foo{life}
\end{document}
```

The data structure here (currently) uses only one name but that means that addition is relatively slow as the size rises. However, lookup should be not so severely affected (it uses a delimited macro), though again this drops off as the table size rises. (For 'big' data sets, TeX's hash table is probably the best way to create a lookup system, as in David's answer. See [How to implement (low-level) arrays in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/how-to-implement-low-level-arrays-in-tex) for more.)

Comment: Wouldn't a `prop` be more efficient here?

Comment: @AndrewStacey I've added a second approach: note that as we currently use on macro for the storage, things do slow down for big data sets. The hash table approach is probably better in those situations: mappings on the other hand are easier with a single macro.

Comment: What do you think: Which method – your 2 approaches and David Carlisles – comes with the best performance?

Comment: @musicman As indicated in the link I've edited in, hash table based approaches have the performance advantage. However, they are not so easy to do certain tasks with (_e.g._ copy the whole table): the best choice depends on your real use case.

Answer (score 7):

The following example compares the strings until a match if found. Then `\@car` takes the first argument and throws the remaining part until and including the next `\@nil` away, so that the following comparisons are skipped:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\foo[1]{%
  \def\foo@##1##2{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{##1}{\@car{##2}}{}%
  }%
  \foo@{givemea}{box}%
  \foo@{drawmea}{circle}%
  \foo@{applesidontlikeare}{green}%
  \foo@{life}{is full of surprises}%
  \@nil
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foo{givemea} \foo{life}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]