# hash (dictionary) data structure

Tags: auxiliary-files

closely related to [How to implement (low-level) arrays in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/how-to-implement-low-level-arrays-in-tex?rq=1) .  What is the recommended package that provides a simple abstraction of the hash feature that is in latex, at least for small-scale needs.  Think

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\hashrestore}
\newcommand{\hashinsert}[2]{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\hashget}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}
\AtEndDocument{\hashsave}
\newcommand{\hashsave}{ ... write to file ... }
\newcommand{\hashretrieve}{ ... load from file ... }
\makeatother
```

It's just one global hash.  This is essentially the same functionality that labels and refs provide through the .aux files.  I know I have hacked around this problem a few times before, but the last times was years ago, and I can't recall how.  I didn't abstract it, either.  Grrr...  Moreover, there may be newer packages that satisfy this need better.  If no one answers this, I will look through my old tex hacks (comp.text.tex) to see what my most recent solution to this issue was.  It's common enough a need to warrant a dedicated tex.stackexchange post.

I will want to use this, e.g., to define

```
\usepackage{hash}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2]{\caption{#2}\label{#1}\hashinsert{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\myinshere}[1]{\begin{center} Insert Table \ref{#1}: \hashget{#1} \end{center}}
```

and in my document

```
...
\myinshere{tbl:1}
...

\begin{table} \mycaption{tbl:1}{Table 1} \end{table}
```

Comment: Always [place the `\label` *after* the `\caption`](http://goo.gl/t01vUD).

Comment: 1) That's not what a hash set is – you're describing a dictionary.  2) You may be able to use property lists in conjunction with distinct external files – take a look at `expl3` (`texdoc expl3; texdoc interface3`).  3)  I don't know why you would want to do this in the first place.  What's the *actual* problem?

Comment: Looks as if you want to use the endfloat package with the markers option.

Comment: @Werner Or _in_ the caption.

Comment: sorry about the label caption misorder.  I was just trying to sketch the application.  I also edited the title.

Comment: ulrike+sean: endfloat with marker is a similar application to my usage illustration, but I want myinshere to print the caption text itself in the text to remind the reader what the table is about.  this is what I need the hash (dictionary) for, in the first place.  expl3 seem to be guidelines to programming and interface3 is very deep.  This goes *way* deeper than what I can deal with.