# Does expl3 have arrays?

Tags: expl3, data-structures

There is `\seq_item:Nn` to get an arbitrary item from a sequence. As far as I understand, this works by iterating the sequence items, discarding until the requested item is found, which seems not very efficient.

Is there a data structure in `expl3` that instead is more array-like in the terms that a single element can be directly accessed? This is something that before `expl3` would have been done by defining macros for each "array item" like

```
\expandafter\def\csname \arrayname \itemnumber\endcsname{\arrayelement}
```

Not very difficult to translate to `expl3` syntax, but perhaps it is already there?

Comment: There's the roadmap in `interface3.pdf` that `\array...` is to be added, so the answer is no, at the moment ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you probably refer to the roadmap of the floating point module l3fp? (Or do you mean something in https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror, `l3db` maybe…?)

Comment: @clemens: I think it's `l3fp`. I did not check further. If you know more on the (plans) of array syntax etc. in `l3` go ahead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, I know nothing. This is one for Joseph or Frank or David…

Comment: @clemens: You're one of the most frequent users of `l3`, apart from egreg, of course, but I think you should participate in the development of it. I just managed to write a cs with `\cs_new:Nn` recently ;-)

Comment: `\prop_put:Nnn`, `\prop_get:NnN` and `\prop_item:Nn`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What clemens means is that you pointed to the `l3fp` roadmap, which is not the roadmap of expl3, and which has nothing to do with an implementation of an array in TeX, it does *not* mean that `\array…` is to be added. It's just another possible use inside `l3fp` macros.

Comment: @Manuel: Well, you're right as always and I am completely wrong, as always, apparently ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not necessarily, I just think that's what clemens meant. May be in the future we can implement arrays *through* `l3fp`.

Comment: @Manuel: And that's why added `l3fp` as a reply to clemens' comment

Comment: @Manuel l3prop poses an interesting alternative. As it is intended for general-purpose mapping, I assume it would introduce much less overhead. Can it store arbitrary tokens, including macros and definitions, as values?

Comment: @XZS A separate question :-) `prop` data is built on `tl` data, and so can happily contain anything.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, `expl3` provides the `prop` data type for key-value type addressing

```
\prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop { a } { data-for-a }
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \prop_get:Nn  \l_tmpa_prop { a } } 
\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl % "data-for-a"
```

At present, this is also implemented using a single underlying macro so extraction in an expandable way has to iterate over the content. A none-expandable accessor function is available and is faster

```
\prop_get:NnN  \l_tmpa_prop { a } \l_tmpa_tl
```

The team have discussed alternative implementations here. As you note, for random access a hash table based approach is faster. However, that comes at the cost of issues with doing mappings (requiring a linked list implementation) and copying the data types (which then requires a mapping).

We are considering providing a generalised object data type, which will then be extensible by (low-level) module authors. However, at present if you need a data structure optimised for random access you will need to build it yourself.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/how-to-implement-low-level-arrays-in-tex

Comment: Wasn't Bruno asking a few weeks ago about how to use `\fontdimen`s as a numer array? Is that related to this?

Comment: @Manuel `\fontdimen` arrays are clever, and Bruno, Will and I talked about them at TUG2015. However, you can only (efficiently) store numerical data that way, indexed by a number. Good for some things but rather specialised. We may well use it for selected internal stuff.