# Nest Latex3 data arrays

Tags: expl3, latex3, data-structures

I tried to emulate someting like a matrix with the Latex3 "objects". It seems like I can nest `prop "objects"` into a `tl "object"` -- at least it does not throw an error.

However, I have no idea how I can access them again.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_my_array_tl
\prop_new:N \l_my_dict_prop
\prop_new:N \l_my_dict_two_prop

% define a prop "object"
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_my_dict_prop {val1=some~value, val2=another~value, val3=a~third~value}

% put prop "objects" into the tl "object"
\tl_put_right:NV \l_my_array_tl \l_my_dict_prop
\tl_put_right:NV \l_my_array_tl \l_my_dict_prop

% now i am lost. How can I access the prop "object" from the tl "object"
% is this even possible? I'd like to save \tl_item:N \l_my_array_tl in \l_my_dict_two_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Is there a way of achieving such a matrix emulation?

Comment: you shouldn't "unpack" a prop with `V`. You get the inner structure inside the \tl-var and that is not usable for you. `V` should only be used with variables with simple values inside.

Comment: There is the [`starray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/starray) package. Also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256807/208544)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you get no error is irrelevant.

Apart from registers, TeX only knows how to store material in macros and `\l_my_dict_prop` is a macro, as is `\l_myarray_tl`.

If you add `\tl_show:N \l_myarray_tl` after the first `\tl_put_right:NV` instruction, you see

```
\l_my_array_tl=\s__prop \__prop_pair:wn val1\s__prop {some
value}\__prop_pair:wn val2\s__prop {another value}\__prop_pair:wn val3\s__prop
{a third value}.
```

which is essentially the same as the `\l_my_dict_prop` is defined.

Property lists are macros with a very specific structure: first `\s__prop` announces what the macro contains (this will be used, for instance, to raise errors if something is used improperly); then comes the data in the form

```
\__prop_pair:wn <key>\s__prop{value}
```

But no programmer (except the team) should ever rely on this particular format which might change in the future.

If you dump the *contents* of some boxes in the basement, you can't hope to recover the boxes later.

Depending on your needs, you might get away with a single property list, so long as you use keys in a suitable way to represent the various parts, which basically is the idea of the `starray` package.