# In TeX how can I define a list of data such that I can use a numerical argument to call for one entry out of the list

Tags: macros, tex-core, arguments

I would like to be able to have a defined macro something like this:

```
\def\testmacro[1]{[54.7],[74.1],[98.5]}
```

Such that when I call

```
\testmacro{2},
```

in a document,

```
74.1
```

is printed.  Is this possible?

Background:

I'm writing a C++ program that will export data to a TeX file.  I have up to twenty items (but sometimes fewer), which have various measurement, like pressure.  This TeX file will call for a template, which will specify how different data is actually printed.  In the template, I will specify that I want to print pressure for the second item *here*.

I'd love to be able to say:

```
\def\pressure1{54.7}
\def\pressure2{74.1}
```

etc, but Tex can't handle numbers in macro names.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159118/how-to-iterate-over-a-comma-separated-list

Comment: @sergiokapone Iterating over items of a list isn't quite the same as accessing particular items. For a more general solution: [How to implement (low-level) arrays in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147966/2693).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can have numbers in command names, you just need to access them indirectly or via non-standard catcodes.

```
\newcount\zcount
\def\pressure{\afterassignment\zpressure\zcount}
\def\zpressure{\csname\string\pressure\the\zcount\endcsname}
\def\zdef#1#2#{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1#2\endcsname}

\zdef\pressure1{54.7}
\zdef\pressure2{74.1}
\zdef\pressure3{98.5}



Pressure 2 is \pressure2.

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to do exactly what I want.  I'm going to play with it a bit - I actually have a bunch of fields for each item (start pressure, end pressure, 02 percentage, etc) so - if I understand correctly - it looks like I'll have to duplicate lines two and three for each field.  Thank you!  This was extremely helpful, and it probably would have taken me a year or two - if I was lucky - to figure it out on my own.

Best Regards,

Ben

Comment: @BenMcCandless  you can do whatever you would  do if you used a,b,c instead of 1,2,3, either separate macros `\pressure1{10}` and `\temperature1{25.6}` or have one macro with two fields `stuff1{{10}{25.6}}`

Answer (score 2):

My solution based on Kpym's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216376/66024)

```
    \documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfmath}
    \begin{document}

    \def\pressureData{{1.2, 3.3, 2.3 ,3.4}}
    \def\pressure#1{\pgfmathparse{\pressureData[#1]}\pgfmathresult}

    \pressure0

    \pressure1

    \pressure2

    \pressure3      

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would you add a data item the way the OP proposes (namely, `\def\pressure314{3.14}`)?

Comment: Thank you!  In my case, being able to add items after the initial declaration is a plus, but this is a great answer for situations where the entire selection of items can be defined at once.  I'll definitely remember this for later.