# Using control sequence names to efficiently store a large amount of characters

Tags: macros, tex-core, performance

When reading the thread about [low-level arrays in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147966/how-to-implement-low-level-arrays-in-tex) I stumbled over a note in  [Bruno Le Floch's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149760/23765):

> A long string of characters is stored more efficiently as a csname than as a list of tokens. This has been used at some point in `l3fp`, storing 10000 decimals of `1/(2pi)` as `\159154943091895...`, to be passed to `\string` when needed.

I can't find that definition in the `l3fp` files and I'm curious how it works. The problem seems to boil down to the question "How do you refer to a control sequence name without knowing the full name?" For example, if you assign a shorter name `\expandafter\let\expandafter\short\csname very long name\endcsname`, you can't refer to the original name with `\short` later because only the meaning is assigned to `\short`. On the other hand, a construction that involves `\def` or similar pretty much defeats the purpose because then you need to store the characters as tokens again.

What is the (plain TeX/e-TeX) pattern used here that makes this efficient string storing work?

Comment: It used to be that way in `l3fp`, but now the same is achieved with `\intarray` which is even more efficient (it uses `\fontdimen`).

Comment: From the section of `l3fp-trig.dtx` where this is done (with a new method, as egreg said): "The memory footprint (1/2 byte per digit) is the same as an earlier method of storing the data as a control sequence name, but the major advantage is that we can unpack specific subsets of the digits without unpacking the 10112 decimals."

Comment: I don't see why you say you need to store the character tokens if using a macro `\edef\zzz{\expandafter\noexpand\csname 1234567890\endcsname}` is equivalent (if you set catcodes up) to `\def\zzz{\1234567890}` and stores the 10 digit number as a single csname, which you can get back the digits via `\meaning\zzz`

Answer (score 3):

After

```
\edef\zzz{\expandafter\noexpand\csname 1234567890\endcsname}
```

The 10 digit number is stored as a single csname, as the definition is equivalent (if you set catcodes up) to

```
\def\zzz{\1234567890}
```

The number can be retrieved by `\meaning\zzz` or `\expandafter\string\zzz` and stripping the respective prefix.