# \lstinputlisting always parses entire source file

Tags: listings

I'm using a lot of `\lstinputlisting` commands to display snippets from a large source file.

For example:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=8244,lastline=8250]{source.c}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=9244,lastline=9250]{source.c}
```

and so on.

Compile time is terrible and I'm pretty sure its because `listings` is parsing the entire file up to the `firstline` for each `\lstinputlisting` command. Compile time is fine when I do something like this:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=14,lastline=34]{source.c}
\lstinputlisting[firstline=24,lastline=44]{source.c}
```

Is there a way of avoiding parsing the entire file each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try a simple benchmark, use TeX to copy the desired range to a temp file each time *then* use `lstinputlisting` to input that file is actually slower.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{l3benchmark}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \CopyPartialFile {mmmm} {
\ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {#1}
\iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#2}
\prg_replicate:nn {#3} {
    \ior_str_get:NN \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_str
}
\prg_replicate:nn {#4} {
    \ior_str_get:NN \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_str
    \iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {\l_tmpa_str}
}
\ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
\iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
}
\NewDocumentCommand \Repeat {mm} { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark_tic:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Repeat{100}{%
\lstinputlisting[firstline=5001,lastline=5020]{source.c}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark_toc:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark_tic:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Repeat{100}{%
\CopyPartialFile{source.c}{tmp.c}{5000}{20}%
\lstinputlisting{tmp.c}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark_toc:
\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

(which makes it likely that `listings` is not actually **parse** these lines, it only read and skip through them)

TeX does not have the feature to "seek to line X of a file" (this is actually fundamentally impossible), so an obvious solution here is to store the whole file into memory and extract the relevant lines when needed.

This solution defines one control sequence for each source code file line to store the line content, then when needed write the content to a temporary file and `\lstinputlisting` it.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{l3benchmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% ======== this block of code read the file source.c and store it into several control sequences ========
\ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {source.c}
\int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
\ior_str_map_variable:NNn \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_str {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \str_set_eq:cN {l__robert_fileline_ \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int _str} \l_tmpa_str
}
\ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior

\cs_new:Npn \__robert_use_file_line:n #1 {
    \use:c {l__robert_fileline_ #1 _str} ^^J
}
% ======== this defines a function \WritePartialToFile{targetfilename.c}{firstline}{lastline}
% which writes lines firstline-lastline of source.c to targetfilename.c ========
\NewDocumentCommand \WritePartialToFile {mmm} {
    \iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {#1}
    \iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow { \int_step_function:nnN {#2} {#3} \__robert_use_file_line:n }
    \iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
}

% ======== auxiliary function for benchmarking ========
\NewDocumentCommand \Repeat {mm} { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark_tic:
\ExplSyntaxOff

% ======== example usage of \WritePartialToFile to input a part of the file ========
\Repeat{100}{%
\WritePartialToFile{tmp.c}{5001}{5020}%
\lstinputlisting{tmp.c}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\benchmark_toc:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

It's about 3× faster than the original code. (because of [hash collision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147966/250119) it's not as fast as it could be, but good enough)

Comment: an implementation of `\CopyPartialFile`-kind in non-expl3 style:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4889/250119

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, thank you so much.

Comment: Interestingly, it's the method in your initial benchmark that has solved my problem (i.e. `\CopyPartialFile{source.c}{tmp.c}{5000}{20}%\lstinputlisting{tmp.c}%`). Using this method on my source file for about 10 to 15 `\lstinputlisting`s now takes 3 seconds, before it took nearly two minutes. For what it's worth my source file is [here](https://github.com/mwenge/iridisalpha/blob/master/src/iridisalpha.asm). If you try it with your benchmark code, you'll find that it's extremely slow with the standard `\lstinputlisting` method but very fast with your `CopyPartialFile` method.