# Confusion regarding strings and numbers in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, comma-separated-list

I'm using a macro that uses `\StrBetween` from `xstring`

It seems to be working great.

However, when I try to use a value that it returns as a coordinate in a tikz picture, I get a confusing error.

Consider this snippet:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21566/3068
\newcommand*\GetListMember[2]{\StrBetween[#2,\number\numexpr#2+1]{,#1,},,\par}%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\A{\GetListMember{1,2,3}{1}}

% This makes me think the value of \A is 1
\node [draw] at (1,0) {\A};

% Uncommenting the following gives an error that is very confusing to me
% \node [draw] at (\A,1) {\A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works, but if I uncomment the last commented line, I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@@cls 

l.18 \node [draw] at (\A,1)
                            {\A};
```

I think I need to convert the value of `\A` to a number, or something, but I don't know how.

p.s. This happens a lot, where an error message contains text that's not in my input file. (In this case `\@@cls`) Is there a way for me to see the intermediate forms? I feel like I'm debugging Lisp code with no `macroexpand-1`.

Thanks, as ever. (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't defined `\A` to be `1` you've defined it to be `\GetListMember{1,2,3}{1}` (you get `1` when `\A` is expanded). TikZ has no idea what to do with `\GetListMember` when it encounters it in a coordinate.
In this case you can use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.
To see the difference consider the following (for clarity I've used `\A` and `\B`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\A{\GetListMember{1,2,3}{1}}
\show\A
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\B{{1,2,3}[0]}
\show\B
\end{document}
```

When you look at the log file you should see:

```
> \A=macro:
->\GetListMember {1,2,3}{1}.
l.7 \show\A
> \B=macro:
->1.
l.9 \show\B
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I always learn so much when I post a question here. I have a vague memory of learning about `\show` in the past, but it didn't occur to me that it might be useful for this type of debugging.

Comment: How would I do the exact same thing, but with a list variable and counter? I have some list variable \mylist, and a counter \i in a foreach loop, but just writing \pgfmathtruncatemacro\B{\mylist}[\i]} fails ....

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is expansion. The line

```
\def\A{\GetListMember{1,2,3}{1}}
```

defines `\A` to be `\GetListMember{1,2,3}{1}`, which is clearly not a number. TeX tries to expand this as part of the internals of `\node`, but `\StrBetween` is not 'expandable. You can see that if you try to force expansion using `\edef`:

```
\edef\A{\GetListMember{1,2,3}{1}}
```

which will also give the same error.

What you need is an expandable comma-list item selector. The `xstring` package does not provide one, but `expl3` does:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\edef\A{\clist_item:nn{1,2,3}{1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\node [draw] at (1,0) {\A};
\node [draw] at (\A,1) {\A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Probably you'll want to wrap up `\clist_item:nn` in a user-level macro.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, I was unaware of `expl3`