# How to apply \ifthenelse check on list member accessed via macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, ifthenelse

Hi and many thanks in advance!

I'm trying to perfom an `\ifthenelse` check on an element, which was extracted out of a list using a macro found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21560/106142). Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do it: `Undefined control sequence` is thrown when trying to do the check. Probably expansion is the problem, but this exceeds my knowledge. MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ifthen,tikz,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% define check
\newcommand{\checkValue}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{#1: true}{#1: false}}

% routine to extract list member
\newcommand*{\getListMember}[2]{%
    \edef\dotheloop{%
        \noexpand\foreach \noexpand\a [count=\noexpand\i] in {#1} {%
            \noexpand\IfEq{\noexpand\i}{#2}{\noexpand\a\noexpand\breakforeach}{}%
    }}%
    \dotheloop
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\checkValue{0}\\    % works
\checkValue{1}\\    % works

\noindent
\def\theItem{\getListMember{0,1}{1}}%
Member to check: \theItem\\
Do check: %\checkValue{\theItem}    % fails: Undefined control sequence.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are expansion issues but since you are loading Ti*k*Z: why don't you just use the built in extraction mechanism?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,tikz,xstring}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% define check
\newcommand{\checkValue}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{#1: true}{#1: false}}


% routine to extract list member
\newcommand*{\getListMemberPgf}[3]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{{#2}[\the\numexpr#3-1]}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\checkValue{0}\\    % works
\checkValue{1}\\    % works

\noindent
\getListMemberPgf{\theItem}{0,1}{1}%
Member to check: \theItem\\
Do check: \checkValue{\theItem}    %  no longer fails.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that if the list does not only contain numbers you need to wrap the items in `"..."`.

Comment: Many thanks! I just did not know about that mechanism. A minor disadvantage is that members of the list cant be accessed directly, but have to be assigned to some command. Nevertheless, this is what I asked for and your solution works very fine for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xparse`, which has functions to *expandably* extract items from comma separated list of values.

You just need to take care of the fact that `expl3` lists are indexed starting from one (which explains the `+1` in the second argument to `\clist_item:nn`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getListMember}{mm}
 {% #1 = clist, #2 = index
  \clist_item:nn { #1 } { #2+1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\saveListMember}{mmm}
 {% #1 = clist, #2 = index, #3 = macro
  \tl_if_exist:NF #1
   {
    \tl_new:N #1
    \tl_set:Nx #3 { \clist_item:nn { #1 } { #2+1 } }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checkValue}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { #1 } { 1 } {#1:~true} {#1:~false}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\checkValue{0}\\  % works
\checkValue{1}    % works

% directly access the member
\noindent
Member to check: \getListMember{0,1}{1}\\
Do check: \checkValue{\getListMember{0,1}{1}}

% alternative, saving the member in a control sequence
\saveListMember{0,1}{1}{\theItem}

\noindent
Member to check: \theItem\\
Do check: \checkValue{\theItem}

\end{document}
```

[image]