# Why does an empty macro take up space within a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

Hi and many thanks in advance!

I'm trying to figure out why an empty macro definition takes up space within the label of a tikz node and prevents the intended alignment. 
(I cannot avoid an empty macro, since its definition is extracted out of a [list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21559/106142), which can contain emtpy entries.)
Please consider the following MWE, where the labels should be left-aligned on the vertical line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=west, inner sep=0}]
    \draw[gray] (0,1) -- (0,-2);
    \def\a{One!}\def\b{And two!}
    \node at (0,0) {\fbox{\a}\fbox{\b}};
    \def\a{}\def\b{Only two!}
    \node at (0,-1) {\fbox{\a}\fbox{\b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \fbox has a border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\fbox has a border of \fboxsep. But you can test if you command is empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=west, inner sep=0}]
    \draw[gray] (0,1) -- (0,-2);
    \def\a{One!}\def\b{And two!}
    \node at (0,0) {\fbox{\a}\fbox{\b}};
    \def\a{}\def\b{Only two!}
    \node at (0,-1) {\ifdefempty{\a}{}{\fbox{\a}}\fbox{\b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'm ashamed! I thought the MWE could reproduce the behaviour of my real problem (actually without `\fbox`), but I just realised that the Python script I generate the latex file with is buggy.