# simplest way to access element of list inside loop

Tags: pdftex, lists, loops

I would like to access the elements of a list inside a loop. Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\def\numbers{1, 2, 3, 4}
\def\MaFFNs{0.19230259, 0.18361065, 0.18027213, 0.17801571}
\def\MaNFNs{0.49030635, 0.49140458, 0.49246621, 0.49363557}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TITLE}
  Text above
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
  \foreach \number [count=\n] in \numbers
  {
    \begin{column}{0.25\textwidth}
      \centering

      Ma $\approx$ \MaFFNs{\number}

      \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figures/porous-FFN-\number}
      \end{figure}

      Ma $\approx$ \MaNFNs{\number}

      \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../figures/porous-NFN-\number}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  }
  \end{columns}
  Text below
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code above works for the figures, but not for the elements in the lists. The solution available in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21566 doesn't work for me (I get `! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.`); indeed, in the solution mentioned, the elements of the list are not accessed inside a loop.

Could someone help me figure out the best (simplest) way to achieve what I want?

Thanks a lot,

EDIT: the solution is simple, as pointed out by David Carlisle below. Replacing `\numbers` for `\ids` and `\number` for `\id`, the solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21566 works.

Comment: don't use `\number` as a local variable, it's a tex primitve and you will get weird low level errors

Comment: Thank you very much, David. You are right: by replacing `\numbers` for `\ids` and `\number` for `\id`, it works.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but if your tex distribution is reasonable new, then you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Beamer also has its own column mechanism, so normally no need for `\usepackage{multicol}`.

Answer (score 2):

don't use `\number` as a local variable, it's a tex primitve and you will get weird low level errors.