How to access specific entry from list of arguments, when index is provided as a letter?
Given a version of an exam paper via \dev\VERSION{C} (C for the third version), I want a command \variants{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}} to produce v3.
I realise that I am effectively trying to access an item from a list or array, but TeX does not seem well equipped for that. I came up with something half working if either I hard-code the version using `C or otherwise if I use \let\VERSION=C (by using the technique from this answer.)
Is there an easier way? I feel like I am overlooking something rather obvious here.
MWE follows.
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
% Objective: Specify a version \VERSION of a document such as A, B, or
% C, and then in various places offer text alternatives via \variant,
% of which \TeX\ chooses the one corresponding to the version (by
% position in the list).
%
% Example:
%   \def\VERSION{C} 
%
% should effect that
%   \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}
% produces v3.
%

\def\VERSION{B}
% \let\VERSION=B  % with this it works, but want \def instead of \let

%% Credit: \zza and \zz due to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21559/19500
\def\zz#1{%
% catcode 11 (letter)
\ifcat a#1%
\expandafter\zza\meaning#1 .\relax
\else
%other cases here
-1
\fi}
\def\zza#1 #2 #3 #4.\relax{`#3 }

% here's the variant code
\def\variants#1{%
  \begingroup
  \newcount\version
  % \expandafter\version=`\VERSION
  % \version=`C % currently hard-coded version works here, want
  %             % something like line above instead
  \let\versionletter=\VERSION
  \version=\zz{\versionletter}
  \advance\version by-64
  \def\thevariants{#1}%
  \def\processvariants##1##2\endofvariants{%
    \global\def\currentvariant{##1}%
    \global\def\thevariants{##2}}%
  \loop
  \expandafter\processvariants\thevariants{NOT ENOUGHT VARIANTS
    SPECIFIED}\endofvariants%
  \advance\version by-1
  \ifnum\version>0\repeat
  \endgroup
  \currentvariant  
  }

\variants{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\end{document}

Due diligence: Accessing items from a list can be done in other ways with possibly more overhead in terms of packages used, e.g. answers here. The difficulty in my scenario stems from turning the letter code into a number.

you have tagged this plain tex and use \def in some places but your example is latex not plain tex. do you need an answer that works in plain tex?

Please specify precisely for each possible  of \VERSION what number it should be mapped to and also specify desired behavior in case \VERSION holds a  for which no mapping to a number is specified.

In the text of your question you ask for a command \variant while in the example code you define a command \variants.

Thanks for the scrutiny. Typo \variant was a typo, this is fixed now. Plain TeX is not exactly a requirement, as I am using LaTeX, but I wanted something with little to no overhead in terms of other packages. The VERSION to number mapping should be A->1, B->2, C->3 etc and a natural end to this is at Z->26. There should be an error or waring if not enough variants are provided. That a non-letter is provided as \VERSION does not happen in my use-case.

This is latex not plain tex as you used a latex example, but it could easily be converted to plain.

\documentclass{article}

\def\variant#1{\csname xVERSION\VERSION\endcsname#1\relax}
\def\xVERSIONA#1#2\relax{#1}
\def\xVERSIONB#1#2#3\relax{#2}
\def\xVERSIONC#1#2#3#4\relax{#3}
\def\xVERSIOND#1#2#3#4#5\relax{#4}
\def\xVERSIONE#1#2#3#4#5#6\relax{#5}

\begin{document}

\def\VERSION{C} \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\def\VERSION{D} \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\def\VERSION{A} \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\end{document}


Or a version that can go past #9 here getting the 13th item for M

\documentclass{article}

\def\variant#1{\expandafter\xversion\expandafter`\VERSION\relax#1\relax}
\def\xversion#1\relax#2{%
  \ifnum#1=`A
    #2\expandafter\xxversion
  \else
    \expandafter\xversion\the\numexpr#1-1\expandafter\relax\expandafter\relax
  \fi}
\def\xxversion#1\relax{}

\begin{document}

\def\VERSION{C} \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\def\VERSION{D} \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\def\VERSION{A} \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\def\VERSION{M} \variant{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}{v5}{v6}{v7}{v8}{v9}{v10}{v11}{v12}{v13}{v14}{v15}}

\end{document}


The second version is basically what I had in mind. I had thought about something similar to the first version but rejected it as too repetitive. I am accepting this answer as it is the closest to what I asked for. Thank you!

@bjoseru thanks and you'll have made egreg so happy, he loves to see me get a green tick:-)

It's quite easy with expl3: with \setvariant you choose the variant (a letter, upper- or lowercase) and \variant will produce the corresponding item.
The letter is converted to an integer (A becomes 1, B becomes 2 and so on) so we can use the integer to extract the item.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setvariant}{m}
 {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_bjoseru_variant_int { \int_from_alph:n { #1 } }
 }
\int_new:N \g_bjoseru_variant_int

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\variants}{m}
 {
  \tl_item:nn { #1 } { \g_bjoseru_variant_int }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setvariant{C}

\variants{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\setvariant{A}

\variants{{v1}{v2}{v3}{v4}}

\end{document}



While I feel that David Carlisle's answer is a smidge closer to what I asked for, I have to admit that I learned more from your answer and ended up learning a few basics of interface3 and now have a version of your answer implemented that deals with a few extra cases and is not much longer and yet very readable. Thanks for sending me down this road ;)

The following example splits the task into the sub-tasks of mapping the replacement text of \VERSION to a natural number k and extracting the kth element of a list of undelimited macro arguments that itself is delivered as an undelimited macro argument.
The routine \variants is expandable, i.e., can be used in expansion-only contexts.
The routine \variants relies on the macro \VERSION being defined as a macro which neither does take arguments nor does take argument delimiters nor has the token !12 in its replacement-text unless nested between {1...}2. (Changing the mapping-routine so that instead of !12 frozen-\relax is forbidden to occur in the replacement text of \VERSION might be a nice exercise.)
With this answer it was decided to implement the mapping based on token-strings and cranking out cases by means of delimited macro arguments so that you can easily enhance to also take version numbers/version-strings into account that do not consist only of single letters, e.g., s.th. like "A.1" or "2.5-beta-3(2024-07-21_16:41:25_UTC_+0000)".
If you don't mind using LaTeX3/LaTeX 2ε's programming layer expl3, then you might be much better off using \str_case:nnTF or the like.
\makeatletter
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <action if there is no K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax##1##2#1{{##1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
%%=============================================================================
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Code for \MapToNumber{<tokens>}
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletoexclam{\long\def\UD@gobbletoexclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@MapForkFirstSet{%
  \long\def\UD@MapForkFirstSet#1!A!B!C!D!E!F!G!H!I!J!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@MapForkSecondSet{%
  \long\def\UD@MapForkSecondSet#1!K!L!M!N!O!P!Q!R!S!T!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@MapForkThirdSet{%
  \long\def\UD@MapForkThirdSet#1!U!V!W!X!Y!Z!a!b!c!d!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@MapFourthSet{%
  \long\def\UD@MapFourthSet#1!e!f!g!h!i!j!k!l!m!n!o!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@MapFifthSet{%
  \long\def\UD@MapFifthSet#1!p!q!r!s!t!u!v!w!x!y!z!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\MapToNumber[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletoexclam#1!}%
  {%
    \UD@MapForkFirstSet
    !#1!B!C!D!E!F!G!H!I!J!{1}% letter A
    !A!#1!C!D!E!F!G!H!I!J!{2}% letter B
    !A!B!#1!D!E!F!G!H!I!J!{3}% letter C
    !A!B!C!#1!E!F!G!H!I!J!{4}% letter D
    !A!B!C!D!#1!F!G!H!I!J!{5}% letter E
    !A!B!C!D!E!#1!G!H!I!J!{6}% letter F
    !A!B!C!D!E!F!#1!H!I!J!{7}% letter G
    !A!B!C!D!E!F!G!#1!I!J!{8}% letter H
    !A!B!C!D!E!F!G!H!#1!J!{9}% letter I
    !A!B!C!D!E!F!G!H!I!#1!{10}% letter J
    !A!B!C!D!E!F!G!H!I!J!{%
      \UD@MapForkSecondSet
      !#1!L!M!N!O!P!Q!R!S!T!{11}% letter K
      !K!#1!M!N!O!P!Q!R!S!T!{12}% letter L
      !K!L!#1!N!O!P!Q!R!S!T!{13}% letter M
      !K!L!M!#1!O!P!Q!R!S!T!{14}% letter N
      !K!L!M!N!#1!P!Q!R!S!T!{15}% letter O
      !K!L!M!N!O!#1!Q!R!S!T!{16}% letter P
      !K!L!M!N!O!P!#1!R!S!T!{17}% letter Q
      !K!L!M!N!O!P!Q!#1!S!T!{18}% letter R
      !K!L!M!N!O!P!Q!R!#1!T!{19}% letter S
      !K!L!M!N!O!P!Q!R!S!#1!{20}% letter T
      !K!L!M!N!O!P!Q!R!S!T!{%
        \UD@MapForkThirdSet
        !#1!V!W!X!Y!Z!a!b!c!d!{21}% letter U
        !U!#1!W!X!Y!Z!a!b!c!d!{22}% letter V
        !U!V!#1!X!Y!Z!a!b!c!d!{23}% letter W
        !U!V!W!#1!Y!Z!a!b!c!d!{24}% letter X
        !U!V!W!X!#1!Z!a!b!c!d!{25}% letter Y
        !U!V!W!X!Y!#1!a!b!c!d!{26}% letter Z
        !U!V!W!X!Y!Z!#1!b!c!d!{1}% letter a
        !U!V!W!X!Y!Z!a!#1!c!d!{2}% letter b
        !U!V!W!X!Y!Z!a!b!#1!d!{3}% letter c
        !U!V!W!X!Y!Z!a!b!c!#1!{4}% letter d
        !U!V!W!X!Y!Z!a!b!c!d!{%
          \UD@MapFourthSet
          !#1!f!g!h!i!j!k!l!m!n!o!{5}% letter e
          !e!#1!g!h!i!j!k!l!m!n!o!{6}% letter f
          !e!f!#1!h!i!j!k!l!m!n!o!{7}% letter g
          !e!f!g!#1!i!j!k!l!m!n!o!{8}% letter h
          !e!f!g!h!#1!j!k!l!m!n!o!{9}% letter i
          !e!f!g!h!i!#1!k!l!m!n!o!{10}% letter j
          !e!f!g!h!i!j!#1!l!m!n!o!{11}% letter k
          !e!f!g!h!i!j!k!#1!m!n!o!{12}% letter l
          !e!f!g!h!i!j!k!l!#1!n!o!{13}% letter m
          !e!f!g!h!i!j!k!l!m!#1!o!{14}% letter n
          !e!f!g!h!i!j!k!l!m!n!#1!{15}% letter o
          !e!f!g!h!i!j!k!l!m!n!o!{%
            \UD@MapFifthSet
            !#1!q!r!s!t!u!v!w!x!y!z!{16}% letter p
            !p!#1!r!s!t!u!v!w!x!y!z!{17}% letter q
            !p!q!#1!s!t!u!v!w!x!y!z!{18}% letter r
            !p!q!r!#1!t!u!v!w!x!y!z!{19}% letter s
            !p!q!r!s!#1!u!v!w!x!y!z!{20}% letter t
            !p!q!r!s!t!#1!v!w!x!y!z!{21}% letter u
            !p!q!r!s!t!u!#1!w!x!y!z!{22}% letter v
            !p!q!r!s!t!u!v!#1!x!y!z!{23}% letter w
            !p!q!r!s!t!u!v!w!#1!y!z!{24}% letter x
            !p!q!r!s!t!u!v!w!x!#1!z!{25}% letter y
            !p!q!r!s!t!u!v!w!x!y!#1!{26}% letter z
            !p!q!r!s!t!u!v!w!x!y!z!{%
              -1% s.th. else without !
            }!!!!%
          }!!!!%
        }!!!!%
      }!!!!%
    }!!!!%
  }{-1}% s.th. else with !
}%
%% End of code for \MapToNumber
%%=============================================================================
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%% Code for 
%%  \variants{<tokens in case no mapping of current replacement text of \VERSION to a number k is defined in \MapToNumber>}
%%           {<tokens in case list contains no k-th argument; number k obtained by mapping the current replacement text of \VERSION to a number k>}
%%           {{...}{...}{...}} % <- List of undelimited arguments itself coming along as an undelimited argument
%%/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\newcommand\variants{%
  \expandafter\@variants
  \expandafter{\number\expandafter\MapToNumber\expandafter{\VERSION}}%
}%
\newcommand\@variants[3]{%
  \ifnum#1<0 \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
  {\UD@firstoftwo{#2}}%
  {\ExtractKthArg{#1}{#3}}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\VERSION{}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\splitmeaning#1->{}%
\def\callvariants#1{%
  \noindent
  \csname toks@\endcsname={#1}%
  \edef\VERSION{\the\csname toks@\endcsname}%
  \texttt{\string\VERSION} is "\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION}". Call to
  \texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\variants} yields:\\
  \variants{%
    Mapping for replacement text "\texttt{%
     \protect\frenchspacing
     \expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION
    }" of \texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\VERSION} not available!%
  }{%
    The replacement text "\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION}" of
    \texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\VERSION} maps to the number \expandafter\MapToNumber\expandafter{\VERSION},
    but the list does not hold a \expandafter\MapToNumber\expandafter{\VERSION}-st/-nd/-rd/-th
    argument!%
  }{%
    {V1}{V2}{V3}{V4}{V5}{V6}{V7}{V8}{V9}{V10}{V11}{V12}{V13}{V14}{V15}{V16}{V17}%
    {V18}{V19}{V20}{V21}{V22}{V23}{V24}{V25}{V26}%
  }%
  \par\medskip
}%

\callvariants{A}
\callvariants{B}
\callvariants{C}
\callvariants{D}
\callvariants{E}
\callvariants{F}
\callvariants{G}
\callvariants{H}
\callvariants{I}
\callvariants{J}
\callvariants{K}
\callvariants{L}
\callvariants{M}
\callvariants{N}
\callvariants{O}
\callvariants{P}
\callvariants{Q}
\callvariants{R}
\callvariants{S}
\callvariants{T}
\callvariants{U}
\callvariants{V}
\callvariants{W}
\callvariants{X}
\callvariants{Y}
\callvariants{Z}
\callvariants{a}
\callvariants{b}
\callvariants{c}
\callvariants{d}
\callvariants{e}
\callvariants{f}
\callvariants{g}
\callvariants{h}
\callvariants{i}
\callvariants{j}
\callvariants{k}
\callvariants{l}
\callvariants{m}
\callvariants{n}
\callvariants{o}
\callvariants{p}
\callvariants{q}
\callvariants{r}
\callvariants{s}
\callvariants{t}
\callvariants{u}
\callvariants{v}
\callvariants{w}
\callvariants{x}
\callvariants{y}
\callvariants{z}
\callvariants{s. th. without mapping}
\callvariants{?}
\callvariants{#}
\callvariants{_}
\callvariants{!A!B!C!D!E!F!G!H!I!J!}

\noindent
\csname toks@\endcsname={C}%
\edef\VERSION{\the\csname toks@\endcsname}%
\texttt{\string\VERSION} is "\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION}". Call to
\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\variants} yields:\\
\variants{%
  Mapping for replacement text "\texttt{%
   \protect\frenchspacing
   \expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION
  }" of \texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\VERSION} not available!%
}{%
  The replacement text "\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION}" of
  \texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\VERSION} maps to the number \expandafter\MapToNumber\expandafter{\VERSION},
  but the list does not hold a \expandafter\MapToNumber\expandafter{\VERSION}-st/-nd/-rd/-th
  argument!%
}{%
  {V1}{V2}{V3}{V4}%
}%
\par\medskip

\noindent
\csname toks@\endcsname={K}%
\edef\VERSION{\the\csname toks@\endcsname}%
\texttt{\string\VERSION} is "\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION}". Call to
\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\variants} yields:\\
\variants{%
  Mapping for replacement text "\texttt{%
   \protect\frenchspacing
   \expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION
  }" of \texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\VERSION} not available!%
}{%
  The replacement text "\texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\expandafter\splitmeaning\meaning\VERSION}" of
  \texttt{\protect\frenchspacing\string\VERSION} maps to the number \expandafter\MapToNumber\expandafter{\VERSION},
  but the list does not hold a \expandafter\MapToNumber\expandafter{\VERSION}-st/-nd/-rd/-th
  argument!%
}{%
  {V1}{V2}{V3}{V4}%
}%

\end{document}



I am quite impressed by this answer and the level of detail it goes into, thank you.
